# Decoding Base64 image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64

I need to convert the image `to/from Base64`.
All working fine for JPG files, but if I upload PNG and then open it in the app it leads to the crash with error

> "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

while trying to create Data from the encoded string

Here is my code:

For Encoding:

```
static  func base64Convert(base64String: String?) -> UIImage {
    var decodedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_prof_image")
    if ((base64String?.isEmpty)! || (base64String?.contains("null"))!) {
        return decodedImage
    }else {
        if  let imageBase64String = base64String,
            let dataDecoded = Data(base64Encoded: imageBase64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
            decodedImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded) ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_prof_image")
        }
        return decodedImage
    }
}
```

For Decoding:

```
static func makeProfileBase64FromImage(image: UIImage) -> String? {
    var imageData : Data?
    if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
        imageData = jpegData
    } else if let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        imageData = pngData
    }
    return imageData?.base64EncodedString()
}
```

What I tried:

**1) All encoding options**

**2) All decoding options**

**3) Swap `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. It leads to the same error but with jpg images.**

**UPDATE**

Here is code how I send data to the server:

```
var imageToSend : String = "null"

        if profileImage.image != #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_prof_image"),
            let validImage = profileImage.image,
            let imageBase64 = AppUtils.makeProfileBase64FromImage(image: validImage) {
            imageToSend = imageBase64
        }

let parameters : Parameters = [
    "image": imageToSend
]

Alamofire.request(AppUtils.API_URL + "update_profile.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
    .validate().responseData() {response in

    switch response.result {
        case .success:
            //...Some stuff
            break
        case .failure:
            //...Some stuff
            break
    }
}
```

Part of the string that came to the server:

```
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
```

**UPDATED CODE IN THE QUESTION**

For now, the code doesn't have force unwrap. But now I always gets standard `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_prof_image")`. (Before, at least jpg works fine :) )

Comment: I think issue is not with conversion. Issue is your image is nill before conversion.

Comment: Th same comment I posted at the answer below applies to your question. The second condition `else if let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` will never be executed. You have to choose which one you would like to use PNG or JPEG. Btw this would be much easier using optional chaining `return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)?.base64EncodedString()`

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, thanks. I'm waited for magic from it and forgot that I already tried it.

Comment: @Kvazios looks like your issue is your PNG data size is much bigger than JPEG data. So your server might have a size limit for your image upload.

Comment: @LeoDabus make an answer you are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your issue is your PNG data size which is much bigger than JPEG data. So your server might have a size limit for your image upload.

Regarding your encoding method The second condition `else if let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` will never be executed. You have to choose which one you would like to use PNG or JPEG data representations (JPEG most times due to the size limit). Btw this would be much easier using optional chaining.

```
return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)?.base64EncodedString()
```

**Swift 4.2 Xcode 10 or later**

```
return image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString()
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite obviously, you use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` for `.jpeg` images, but for `.png` images you should use `UIImagePNGRepresentation`

Also, don't use force unwrapping.

```
static func makeBase64FromImage(image: UIImage) -> String? {
    var imageData : Data?
    if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
        imageData = jpegData
    } else if let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        imageData = pngData
    }
    return imageData?.base64EncodedString()
}
```

Comment: @Kvazios are you sure you tried the variation proposed here? the code above attempts to use UIImageJPEGRepresentation, if that fails then attempt PNG.  It should work.  Can you please try this and show what's the error you get?

Comment: @ekscrypto Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. `dataDecoded` is nil

Comment: Then you are clearly still using force-unwrapping somewhere

Comment: The second condition `else if let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` will never be executed. You have to choose which one you would like to use PNG or JPEG. Btw this would be much easier using optional chaining `return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)?.base64EncodedString()`

Comment: Actually the second can be executed but if it does it will fail also.

Comment: @LeoDabus `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` both return optional `Data?` - either a valid `Data` representation of image, or `nil`. And like OP said, `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` fails for `.png` images, so the simple one-liner unfortunately will not work

Comment: If it fails for JPEG it will fail for PNG also

Answer (score 1):

As @mag_zbc suggested, start with:

```
static func makeBase64FromImage(image: UIImage) -> String? {
    var imageData : Data?
    if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
        imageData = jpegData
    } else if let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        imageData = pngData
    }
    return imageData?.base64EncodedString()
}
```

Then, update this code to:

```
var imageToSend : String = "null"
if profileImage.image != #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_prof_image"),
   let validImage = profileImage.image,
   let imageBase64 = AppUtils.makeBase64FromImage(image: validImage) {
       imageToSend = imageBase64
}
let parameters : Parameters = [
    "image": imageToSend
]
...
```

In general, you want to avoid using "!" anywhere unless you can 100% confirm that in any and all cases the value will always be defined.  In this case, I believe the issue was your code being called with profileImage.image == nil

A profileImage.image being nil would != to the image literal, and therefore would have entered the conditional if you defined.  Then by forcing it to be unwrapped with "!" you tried to unwrap nil.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the try, but not helped. In fact, when I open uploaded image from Android it looks cropped (half of the image is black)

Comment: Well now, at least you no longer have your tried to unwrap nil error.  Which solves your original question.  I'm guessing you now have an issue somewhere else.

Comment: Error still the same

Comment: @Kvazios then update your question specifying exactly which line is giving you the error.  I highly suspect, if you updated the code properly, that the error is now somewhere else in your code.